# Wubi installer stuck on 75%

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

I'm currently installing Wubi, and the installer keeps getting stuck at about 75% - I have had this problem before and I think I managed to fix it by resetting/stopping something in Windows when booting into that, but i cant remember what it was. The last text in the installer (if it helps)is:

```
ubuntu kernel: [ 483.749080] [<c1064d60>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x60/0x60
ubuntu kernel: [ 483.749080] [<c15d04fe>] kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10
```

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Are you installing with the 32-bit ISO? What graphics card do you have? What release of Ubuntu? Please can you add your wubi log file to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1182805) (in `%temp%` directory called `wubi-nn.nn-revnnn.log`). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a terminal and capture the logs:

```
sudo zip -r /host/ubuntu/logs.zip /var/log
```

Then sometimes returning to the installer unfreezes it allowing the install to complete: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

When you've got the logs, please file a bug and attach the logs (`C:\ubuntu\logs.zip`) to it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+filebug

If you get stuck, you can return to the terminal and run `sudo reboot`